# Converting a (YAML) file to any MAP implementation

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, linkedhashmap

I was working on a spare time project where I needed to read values from a YAML file and store them in a `HashMap`, another YAML file had to be stored in a `LinkedHashMap`. I used an API to do the reading, some explanation was added in the code below (though I believe it's quite redundant). Only the method that returns a `LinkedHashMap` was included because the other one is practically identical.

Currently I'm using seperate methods for getting a `HashMap` and `LinkedHashMap` but noticed that the code was quite similar. So I wondered, would it be possible to write a general method that puts the paths and values from the YAML file into any `Collections` implementation (that are implementing `Hash Table`)? And if so, how could one accomplish that?

```
public LinkedHashMap<String, Object> fileToLinkedHashMap(File yamlFile)
{
    LinkedHashMap<String, Object> fileContents = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();

    //Part of the API I'm using, reads from YAML File and stores the contents
    YamlConfiguration config = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(yamlFile);

    //Configuration#getKeys(true) Gets all paths within the read File
    for (String path : config.getKeys(true))
    {
        //Gets the value of a path
        if (config.get(path) != null)
            fileContents.put(path, config.get(path));
    }

    return fileContents;
}
```

Note: I know I'm currently not checking if the given file is a YAML file, this is redundant within this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of functional interfaces (introduced in java 8) for this:

```
public void consumeFile(File yamlFile, BiConsumer<? super String, ? super Object> consumer){
    YamlConfiguration config = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(yamlFile);
    for (String path : config.getKeys(true)){
        if (config.get(path) != null){
            consumer.accept(path, config.get(path));
        }
    }
}
```

Which can then be called with literally anything, you just have to provide a lambda which accepts 2 parameters:

```
// collect into a map
Map<String, Object> map = /* hash map, linked hash map, tree map, you decide */;
consumeFile(yamlFile, map::put);

// just print them, why not?
consumeFile(yamlFile, (key, value) -> System.out.println(key + " = " + value));
```

You see, the uses are possibly endless. Only limited by your use case and imagination.

If you can't use java 8 (you probably should though) there is still hope. As you both times return a `Map` you can decide when calling the method what map implementation you'd like to collect into:

```
public Map<String, Object> consumeFile(File yamlFile, Map<String, Object> map){
    YamlConfiguration config = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(yamlFile);
    for (String path : config.getKeys(true)){
        if (config.get(path) != null){
            map.put(path, config.get(path));
        }
    }
    return map;
}
```

Which may be called like this:

```
Map<String, Object> map = consumeFile(yamlFile, new /*Linked*/HashMap<>());
```

Again what map implementation you want to use, you can decide for your needs.

Comment: Probably there is a dup for that somewhere, but whatever: nice answer, nice examples!